# Nested Vue component not displaying

Tags: vue.js, websphere

I adopted this code and understand it's not the typical .vue file format. It runs inside a WebSphere portlet that has other Vue code running.

The first level component loads just fine (greeting-portlet-text) but the nested one (greeting-portlet-buttons) seems to be completely ignored.  I recently added that one using the same format as the other components in this file.  I'm puzzled why it does not work.

```
Vue.component('greeting-portlet-text', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      today: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getFormattedTodaysDate: function() {
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
      return today;
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.today = this.getFormattedTodaysDate();
  },
  template:
    '<div class="greeting-text"><h1>Welcome ' +
    _greentin_app_config.user.firstName +
    '</h1>' +
    '  <div class="greeting-buttons greeting-buttons-top show-for-large">' + 
    '    <greeting-portlet-buttons></greeting-portlet-buttons>' +
    '  </div>' +
    '</div>'
});

Vue.component('greeting-portlet-buttons', {
    data: function() {
        return {
              SmartDriveLink: '/wps/myportal/k/payroll/bonus',
              SmartDriveScore: 4
            };
    },
    template:
          '    <a v-if="SmartDriveScore>=25 && SmartDriveScore!=99999" :href="SmartDriveLink" class="button expanded mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--red-A700 mdl-color-text--white">SmartDrive Score:&nbsp;&nbsp; {{SmartDriveScore}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">thumb_down_alt</i></a>' +
          '    <a v-if="SmartDriveScore=== 99999" :href="SmartDriveLink" class="button expanded mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--yellow">SmartDrive Score:&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">phone_in_talk</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;CALL DDM</a>' + 
          '    <a v-if="SmartDriveScore<25" :href="SmartDriveLink" class="button expanded mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--green mdl-color-text--white">SmartDrive Score:&nbsp;&nbsp; {{SmartDriveScore}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">thumb_up_alt</i></a>'
});

(window.onload = function() {
  new Vue({
    el: targetEl,
    template:
      '<div class="greeting-portlet">' +
      '    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">' +
      '        <div class="cell small-12 large-5"><greeting-portlet-text></greeting-portlet-text></div>' +
      '    </div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
})
```

I tried various things such as assigning a name property to greeting-portlet-buttons, adding it as a components object in the outer component, and so far nothing works.

Is this a really old way of doing this or is this typical for Vue and WebSphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap template of the `greeting-portlet-buttons` component into a root element. It's necessary for a component template.

```js
Vue.component('greeting-portlet-text', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      today: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getFormattedTodaysDate: function() {
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
      return today;
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.today = this.getFormattedTodaysDate();
  },
  template:
    '<div class="greeting-text"><h1>Welcome ' +

    // Max: looks like this is an external variable
    '_greentin_app_config.user.firstName' +

    '</h1>' +
    '  <div class="greeting-buttons greeting-buttons-top show-for-large">' + 
    '    <greeting-portlet-buttons></greeting-portlet-buttons>' +
    '  </div>' +
    '</div>'
});

Vue.component('greeting-portlet-buttons', {
    data: function() {
        return {
              SmartDriveLink: '/wps/myportal/k/payroll/bonus',
              SmartDriveScore: 4
            };
    },
    template:

          // Max: I've added <div> as root element
       '<div>'+
          '    <a v-if="SmartDriveScore>=25 && SmartDriveScore!=99999" :href="SmartDriveLink" class="button expanded mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--red-A700 mdl-color-text--white">SmartDrive Score:&nbsp;&nbsp; {{SmartDriveScore}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">thumb_down_alt</i></a>' +
          '    <a v-if="SmartDriveScore=== 99999" :href="SmartDriveLink" class="button expanded mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--yellow">SmartDrive Score:&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">phone_in_talk</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;CALL DDM</a>' + 
          '    <a v-if="SmartDriveScore<25" :href="SmartDriveLink" class="button expanded mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--green mdl-color-text--white">SmartDrive Score:&nbsp;&nbsp; {{SmartDriveScore}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">thumb_up_alt</i></a>' +
          '</div>'
});


(window.onload = function() {
  new Vue({
    el: document.getElementById('app'),
    template:
      '<div class="greeting-portlet">' +
      '    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">' +
      '        <div class="cell small-12 large-5"><greeting-portlet-text></greeting-portlet-text></div>' +
      '    </div>' +
      '</div>'
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: OMG, something so simple and I didn't find that anywhere.  So, as a rule, every component must be wrapped in a root element.  It can't just be a handful of elements in the template section.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element